# File isn't sent fully across Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send a file from a client to a server.
This is the method used on the client's side:

```
public void uploadFile(Socket socket, String path) {
    try (BufferedInputStream file = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path))) {
        BufferedOutputStream uploader = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = file.read(bytes)) != -1)
            uploader.write(bytes, 0, count);
        uploader.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the method on the server's side:

```
public void downloadFile(Socket socket, String path) {
    try (BufferedOutputStream file = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path))){
        BufferedInputStream downloader = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int count;
        while ((count = downloader.read(bytes)) != -1)
            file.write(bytes, 0, count);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Respounder.downloadFile("+path+"): IOException");
    }
}
```

I tried sending a jpg image, with a size of 3627997 bytes but the file saved in the server is 3489153 bytes and the image is corrupted and can't be displayed. But sometimes the code seems to work and the sent image is displayable even though I haven't changed anything, I don't know why. But even when it works, checking the file size I notice there is some difference between the size of the original file and the one sent to the server, about 2 kilobytes.

Comment: What you have looks like it should work (though should not continue after exceptions). In JDK1.8+ you can save a lot of error prone typing with `Files.copy(Path.of(path), socket.getOutputStream())` and `Files.copy(socket.getInputStream(), Path.of(path))`. Check you aren't accessing the streams in other calls not shown.

Comment: You don't seem to close anything. You don't close any streams or sockets, anywhere.

Comment: You must be doing some other I/O with the socket. Don’t.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Because I open the socket in the main method that calls them, the socket is closed there.

Comment: @user207421 Only these two methods are called. Nothing else does anything with the socket.

Comment: @DuncG I double-checked, I'm not accessing the streams outside of these two methods. But I tried Files.copy and it worked without any data loss, thanks!

Comment: As always, you should provide a [mre] rather than a fragment that doesn't reflect what's happening in the actual code.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you are writing/reading straight to/from sockets. If you are not using any protocol then you will have to be very careful of what gets written and read from the socket. Make sure you are not writing anything else to the socket. Similarly, when reading from the socket if you read anything irrelevant then it will get written to the file which will most likely corrupt the output file.

One thing im not sure of is that you are closing the output stream of the socket as soon as your done writing the file. The server might not have finished reading the data mean while. Closing of the socket in the middle of this should not be an issue as it really should trigger cleanup of resource on the client side and eventually on the server (i hope) but try adding a delay or something for testing purposes and then find an elegant way to do this if it helps.

Comment: Adding a delay before close will accomplish exactly nothing. Whether the server has finished reading the data when the client closes is irrelevant.